# JS copy to clipboard dosn't work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, clipboard

I use fetch to get some text and put this text into textarea. Then I select the text and trying to copy it, but it's not working. Here's the code.

```
 const copy_text_from_file = (filename) => {
  fetch('/texts/show/?filename=' + filename, {
    credentials: 'include'
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    const textarea = document.getElementById('clipboard');
    textarea.focus();
    textarea.innerHTML = json.content;
    textarea.select();
    console.log( document.execCommand('copy') ); // writes false to console
  });
};
```

Text is inserted and textarea is selected and is in focus, but nothing is copied. When I run `document.execCommand('copy')` from browser's console it works. I tried adding timeouts but it doesn't help. I tried adding button with click event listener and trigger button with `click()` to copy selected text, but it doen't help either.

PS Textarea is visible.

Comment: You'll need to provide browser information as well

Comment: Do you need to turn designMode on? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/designMode